# Service worker fetching data / working with dom

Tags: javascript, dom, service-worker

How can I fetch and manipulate some data from server (firebase)? For example, I have some user data in firebase and I want to fetch this data when user is signed in. Second question is - Can I manipulate DOM inside service worker? For example I want to render `div`, when function calls. Is there some way to do like that?

```
const renderDiv = () => {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = 'Some text'
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot manipulate DOM in any way from SW. SW does not have any access to DOM.